# How do I change gears in the NAMCO home version of the old school arcade game Pole Position?

Tags: pole-position

We have a NAMCO home version of the arcade game *Pole Position*, but no instructions. The other games work just like their arcade counterparts, but when I play *Pole Position* I can't seem to shift gears and therefore can't pass my computer opponent. Is there a solution, or was this game marketed without the ability to change gears?

[image: Game]

Comment: [What gear are you in?!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyJItQYPXQc)

Comment: There's a joke behind the question, and you'll understand it by clicking the link :).

Answer (score 2):

I remember having an older version of one of these years ago. Took me forever to figure it out, but you must **rotate or twist the joystick to change gears.** Clockwise shifts up, and counter-clockwise to shift down.